# Flex DataGrid 'verticalGridLines and horizontalGridLines'

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex, datagrid, adobe

Friends,

I am using DataGrid in one of my flex application. But, I don't want the DataGrid vertical and horizontal lines to appear within that DataGrid.

So, I used style of `verticalGridLines` and `horizontalGridLines`.

> But, the problem is, I want **some specific vertical and horizontal**
>   lines to be removed. By using above styles, all vertical and
>   horizontal lines were getting removed.

How to handle this problem ? Any solution ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Style property of the datagrid verticalGridLines and horizontalGridLines is used for visibility of grid lines is either true or false. The default value is true.

for more information you can refer [Here](http://examples.adobe.com/flex2/consulting/styleexplorer/Flex2StyleExplorer.html)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to customize the dataGrid to draw specific gird lines then you should consider extending the data grid and override [drawHorizontalLine](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DataGrid.html#drawHorizontalLine%28%29) and [drawVerticalLine](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/controls/DataGrid.html#drawVerticalLine%28%29) with your custom drawing logic.